# How to query for entities by their string collection values LIKE

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, filtering, jpa

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class SystemLogEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private long creationTime;
    private String thread;
    private int severity;
    @Lob
    private String message;
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Lob
    private List<String> stacktrace;

    ...
}
```

My `Respository` implements `JpaSpecificationExecutor`, which allows me to use `Specification`s to filter my db requests:

```
@Repository
public interface SystemLogRepository extends JpaRepository<SystemLogEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<SystemLogEntity> {

     public List<SystemLogEntity> findAll(Specification spec);
}
```

For the simple field of the `SystemLogEntity` this works fine, the `Predicate` are straight forward.

Also if I filter for an exact item in a collection, the `Predicate` are still straight forward (`in`).

But how can I filter my `SystemLogEntity` after a stack trace collection item which is `LIKE` a given value?

In other words, I would e.g. like to filter `SystemLogEntity` after the term `NullpointerException`. Is this even possible with `Predicate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will work:

```java
Specification<SystemLogEntity> stacktraceLike(String stacktrace) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> cb.like(root.join("stacktrace"), "%" + stacktrace + "%");
}
```

More [examples](https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/blob/b6254a7023d324bfc2e675d733533bcc3267df3f/src/test/java/restsdemo/example12/OneTwoTest.java#L101)...

Comment: Exactly this. Thanks